# A problem on normal distribution.

Tags: probability

> The lifetime of a component in a computer is advertised to last for $500$ hours. It is known that the lifetime follows a normal distribution with mean $5100$ hours and standard deviation $200$ hours.
>
> (i) Calculate the probability that a randomly chosen component will last longer than the advertised hours.
>
> (ii) If a dealer wants to be sure that $98\%$ of all the components for sale lasts longer than the advertised figure, what figure should be advertised?

Comment: What have you tried? You might also want to check the question numbers for typos

Comment: The mean should be 510 or 5100?

Comment: Perhaps the answer to (i) is about $0.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999767$

Comment: @henry, Out of curiosity. How did you get that number from EXCEL?

Comment: @satishramanathan `=NORM.DIST(500,5100,200,TRUE)` gives `2.33E-117` which I then subtracted from $1$, though in fact I used R and `pnorm(500,mean=5100,sd=200)` which gave the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
Part I 
$P(X\ge500) = 1-P(X\le500) = 1-P(\frac{X-5100}{200}\le \frac{500-5100}{200})$

$1 - P(z\le -23) \approx 1$

Part II

$P(X\ge x) = 0.98 => 1-P(X\le x) = 0.98 =>P(X\le x) = 0.02$

$ \frac{X-5100}{200} = -2.053748911 => X = 4689$

Answer (score 0):

$x \sim  N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.
Now one can calculate z as:
$z = (x-\mu) / \sigma $
(i) in this case we can have z score as
$z = (500 - 510)/200 = -0.05 $
now we can see the z-table to see 
the probability below or equal to the z value.
Then one can calculate the probability greater than z value as
1-p(z).
    (ii) in this case you are provided with the $\alpha = 0.98$ so you need to calculate the z value.And then calculate X value for it correspondingly.